# TypeError: .splice Cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a cloud function in javascript for Google firestore. It needs to cycle through registration tokens and delete the unnecessary ones I think I have most of the code down but for some reason it doesn't like me calling splice on an array, I'm not a javascript developer and this has me baffled, I'll post the whole script here as its not very big, any help appreciated

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.notifyNewMessage = functions.firestore.document
('users/{ID}/contacts/{contactID}/messages/{messageID}')
    .onCreate((docSnapshot , context) => {
         const message = docSnapshot.data()
         const recipientId = message['recipientId']
         const senderId = message['sender']
         const senderName = message['senderName']

         return admin.firestore().doc('users/' + recipientId + 
                                      "/token/token").get().then(userDoc =>{
    const registrationTokens = userDoc.get('token')
    const notificationBody = (message['data_type'] === "TEXT") ? message['message'] : "You received a new mage message."
    const payload = {
        notification : {
            title : senderName + "sent you a message.",
            body : notificationBody,
            clickAction : "MessageListActivity"
        },
        data : {
            USER_NAME : senderName,
            USER_NUMBER : message['sender']
        }
    }

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens,payload).then(response => {
        const stillRegisteredTokens = registrationTokens



        response.results.forEach((result , index) => {
            const error = result.error
            if(error){
                const  failedRegistrationToken = registrationTokens[index]
                console.error('failed token ', failedRegistrationToken, error)
                if(error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' 
                || error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered')
                {   const failedIndex = stillRegisteredTokens.indexOf(failedRegistrationToken)
                    if(failedIndex > -1){
                        stillRegisteredTokens.splice(failedIndex, 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        return admin.firestore().doc("users" + recipientId + "token" + "token").update({
            registrationTokens : stillRegisteredTokens
        })

    })
})
})
```

Comment: My best guess it that `stillRegisteredTokens` is not an array. I.e. that `const registrationTokens = userDoc.get('token')` does not return an array. You might want to `console.log(JSON.stringify(registrationTokens))` to see what type it actually is.

Comment: Think your right many thanks, will check what it is and post back